# removing /index from the url on htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current urls look like this `[mysite].com/index`

I removed .php's with the following .htaccess code but i can not remove the index from the url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can i remove 'index' from the url?

**EDIT**

**I found why it does not work because of windows hostings does not support htaccess method.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, removing the page name for good it's not a good practice.

It may cause errors, and it's not good for SEO.

I strong suggest you to use friendly URL to remove the PHP extension(the way you're doing right now) or put some other name more friendly.

Exemple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/?$           /my_new_index.php             [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^new-order/?$      /new_order_from_client.php    [NC,L]
```

It's the best practice!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Now apache will treat index.php as directory index and you don't have to type index or index.php in url bar.